# IE 9 and IE 8 display cross sign while search in text box

Tags: internet-explorer

i have issue while i search  it display cross sign in IE (9, 8 ).

in IE 10 its display but using following code issues are solve

::-ms-clear {

display: none;

}

anyone know how to solve that

but it is still display in IE 9 and IE 8

check screen shot[image]

please help me.
thanks in advance

Comment: you need to post what code you have currently if you need help. What you have asked is the equivalent of my car is broke the engine makes a funny sound please help me fix it.

Comment: need to attach your code pal...